# Mixed debugging C++ | Python does not work as expected

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb

I am currently trying to debug my C++ shared library in VS-Code running under Windows 10 with the MSYS2 gdb.exe. Here's my C++ source code:

[image: C++ source code]

I'm compiling the code with the mingw64 g++ compiler:

```
[1/2] "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++" "-Ilibmecos.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "-I..\include" "-fdiagnostics-color=always" "-pipe" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-Wall" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wextra" "-Wpedantic" "-std=c++2a" "-g" -MD -MQ libmecos.dll.p/src_libmecos.cpp.obj -MF "libmecos.dll.p\src_libmecos.cpp.obj.d" -o libmecos.dll.p/src_libmecos.cpp.obj "-c" ../src/libmecos.cpp
[2/2] "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++"  -o libmecos.dll libmecos.dll.p/src_libmecos.cpp.obj "-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined" "-shared" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,--out-implib=libmecos.dll.a" "-lkernel32" "-luser32" "-lgdi32" "-lwinspool" "-lshell32" "-lole32" "-loleaut32" "-luuid" "-lcomdlg32" "-ladvapi32" "-Wl,--end-group"
```

The buildtype is "debug" as indicated by the "-g" flag.

The python file I'm trying to debug is shown subsequently:

[image: Python source code]

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) attach",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "program": "C:/Users/c565785/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe",
            "processId":"${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm launching the debugging of the Python file with "Python current file" command:
[image: Start Python debug]

Now the gdb attach task is invoked and I'm prompted for the processId which I want to attach to:

[image: Attach to process]

```
cmd /C "c:\Users\c565785\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.12.4-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-vs32hlte.zbv --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-r
y5yzxlg.foe --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-batjxwmd.kgp --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-rtdhtuvq.yz4 --dbgExe=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
```

The process is correctly attached, however when continueing the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint set on `line 3` in `libmecos.cpp`.

When I debug the share library directly however, everything works as expected:

```
C:\ProjTMS\MecosTools\dbg\src>gdb python
GNU gdb (GDB) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".    
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.   
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python...        
(No debugging symbols found in python)
(gdb) b libmecos.cpp:3
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (libmecos.cpp:3) pending.
(gdb) run test.py 
Starting program: C:\Users\c565785\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe test.py
[New Thread 6752.0x82e8]
[New Thread 6752.0x2be0]
[New Thread 6752.0x3210]
6752

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, add (x=1, y=5) at ../src/libmecos.cpp:3
3         int z = x + y;
(gdb)
```

It seems like in VS Code the breakpoint is not set correctly. The files are all in the same directory `src`

- `test.py`
- `libmecos.dll`
- `libmecos.cpp`

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

---

Rev. 25.10.2022:
When I launch my debug session with

```
        {
            "name": "C++ debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "program": "C:/Users/c565785/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "args": ["src/test.py"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
        }
```

everything works as expected as well:
[image: Debug the shared library directly]

Comment: have you tried setting the breakpoint _after_ attaching the process? pending breakpoints are a delicate feature. VSCode may silently answer "no" to the gdb question somehow

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes I tried it - no success however.

Comment: can you have access to the gdb console from VS code so you can use "info break" and get the actual breakpoint list that gdb could set?

Comment: Apparently I cannot interact with the gdb console while the process is running. I tried it in the tab "Debug Console", however it says "Unable to perform this action because the process is running."

Comment: Is there a way to interrupt the process with the menu? There should be an "interrupt" option.

Comment: When I debug the shared library only, i.e. launch gdb on the python.exe and start the Python script, the debugger stops at the desired breakpoint and then I'm able to interact with it. However using the attach command, the process is running and I cannot find a way to interrupt it.

Comment: My technique for that is to make the running exe (the one that dynamically loads the dll) "collaborate" by sending a `DebugBreak();` call itself if, say, an environment variable is set as soon as the dll is loaded. Then you can get hold of the gdb prompt and put breakpoints that are not "pending". Other ways are unreliable for reasons I ignore. You can also embed that in your dll (in the "init" routine of your dll)

Comment: So you are suggesting to add a `DebugBreak();` somewhere in the C++ code? This is not a built-in functionality is it?

Comment: yes it is in windows.h. It amounts to `asm("int 03")`

Comment: I've added `DebugBreak();` at the beginning of the function and built it successfully, however it seems to have no effect.